# destroying all other activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I was trying to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` but I found out it's little different from my situation.

In my project, there is three activities, A, B, C.

It moves like A -> B -> C and when activity C is created, activity A and B is destroyed. Should I use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` or other apis?

Thanks.

Comment: When A starts B, should A still exist? (ie: can the user go back from B to A?). Also, what should happen when user presses BACK in C?

Comment: A should exist when A starts B and when user Presses back in C would close the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to finish `A` and `B` activities when starting `C` activity, then to intent used for starting `C` activity add following flags:

```
cActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
cActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using the "dispatcher" mechanism. When `B` wants to start `C`, it should instead tell `A` to do it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("startC", true);
// If B needs to pass additional parameters to C via A add them here
intent.putExtra("key1", value1);
intent.putExtra("key2", value2);
...
startActivity(intent);
```

This will finish `B` and `A`, create a new instance of `A` and call `onCreate()` on the new instance of `A`. In `onCreate()` of `A`, do this:

```
super.onCreate(...);
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra("startC")) {
    // Need to start C
    intent.setClass(this, C.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    return;
}
```

This will cause `A` to start `C` and finish himself. Any extras that are in the `Intent` will be passed on to `C`.